# What is the type of variable?

Tags: c, ruby

Im working on Ruby c extension, I have following code from c program,

```
VALUE var = myFunction(arg1, arg2);
int varType = TYPE(var);
printf("Type of the var is :: %d", varType);
```

Above printf gives output as follow:

```
Type of the var is :: 34
```

As myFunction is inbuild function i dont know the return type of that function.
can any one tell me the type of "var" variable return from myFunction? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the function prototype of the function in the header file of the libray or the SDK, whatever it is a part of.

Comment: does your int varType map to something?  Else the type of var would be an int I guess

Comment: @TonyTheLion: Not really, You cannot say so unless you see what `TYPE()` does, it might be an macro which maps say a string to an int and returns the int.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `TYPE` macro returns values enumerated in [ruby.h](http://svn.joyent.com/opensource/dtrace/ruby/ruby-1.8.5/ruby.h). From there, it follows 34 is T_DATA, which is a [wrapped C structure](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/ruby_tutorial/Extending_Ruby_Wrapping_C_Structures.html).

Comment: jpalecek, i have a question, can we find the exact type of class of that variable i.e. var. myFunction() function return object of some class. i have to find the class name. Any suggestion to find the class name?

Answer (score 0):

var RETURNING FROM MyFunction is type of VALUE

and VALUE is typedef defined in ruby.h

definition

```
typedef unsigned long VALUE;
```