# how to know the type of a variable?

Tags: c, ruby

Im working with Ruby c extension, I have following sample code,

```
const char varP[] = "exceptionString";
VALUE reValue = rb_funcall(*Ptr, rb_intern("exception"), 1, rb_str_new2(varP));
```

rb_funcall() function returns the new object of a class and it is stored in "reValue" variable.
How we can know the class name of value returned by rb_funcall()?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: same is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7647556/what-is-the-type-of-variable

Comment: Thanks Mr.32, but in my case the reValue is object of a used defined class. So how can i get that class name?

Comment: oh if it is user defined class then you should know its class

Comment: Actually, what rb_funcall() function will return when we invoked "exception" method of Exception class by on a pointer "*Ptr"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can find this all just by googling...this function is defined in ruby.h

see this 
http://svn.joyent.com/opensource/dtrace/ruby/ruby-1.8.5/ruby.h